# jquery load() with progress image problem

Tags: jquery

I want to load remote content of parent div upon click of image.
While waiting for the content to load I want to show a progress-image,
now what's wrong with this code?

If i comment the row with preload image, everything works.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img.taskzoom").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().html('<img src="prog.png"/>');
    alert('alert does n\'t help');
    $(this).parent().load('test.php');
  })
});
```

test.php:

```
<?php sleep(3); echo 'server content';?>
```

//clarification//

WITH preload image, the preload image shows, but not remote content.

WO preload image, the remote content shows up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you replace the HTML of the parent element, you detach the image that was clicked.  The element exists as `this` within your handler function, but it is not attached to the DOM.  When you call `parent`, therefore, there is no parent element to find, so the `load` call doesn't work.

If you want to overwrite the whole content of the parent element, you'll need to cache the parent element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img.taskzoom").click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    parent.html('<img src="prog.png"/>');
    alert('alert isn\'t necessary now');
    parent.load('test.php');
  })
});
```

If you don't want to overwrite the whole content, you'll need to do something different.  It's hard to say exactly what without knowing what you want to do!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this?:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img.taskzoom").click(function() {
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    $parent.html('<img src="prog.png"/>');
    $(this).parent().load('test.php', function(response, status, xhr) {
       $parent.html(response);
    });  
  });
});
```